# Generate terrain with plateaus for an RTS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to randomly generate terrain in Unity for an RTS game that I'm developing. I've tried both mesh generation through noise overlapping, as well as some already made assets like MapMagic or GAIA, but none of the this solutions have managed to achieve a result close to what I want.

The problem is that I want to generate islands similar to the ones in the Anno series, with mountains and beaches, but very or mostly flat on the surface, for the player to build a base on it.

The closest I've gotten to this is via a perlin noise generation, but I can't manage to get the plateau like terrain in the island.

Has anyone managed to get generation close to this in Unity and could point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: this would be more or less what I want achieve:
https://images.app.goo.gl/Wx8SSxe1S4s6R7Uv9

Comment: Post some pictures what you want to achieve

Comment: @Menyus something like this: https://images.app.goo.gl/Wx8SSxe1S4s6R7Uv9

Comment: in the dev blog that image links to, he says the islands are handcrafted, not generated

Comment: @yes I know. The thing is if something similar could be achieved via procedural generation

Comment: ProGen terrain algorithms are varied and complex. As such this question is not fit for stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Generate a heightmap.
2. Create an algorithm that normalizes a section of the values in the heightmap based on a min/max falloff range. Everything within the range gets a specific value, which will become the plane/plateau. The ranges of values above and below the falloff get remapped to account for the "missing" difference between original and falloff, to avoid sudden "jumps" in the terrain geometry.
3. Apply the algorithm to the heightmap to get the finalized heightmap.
4. Generate the terrain according to the heightmap.
5. Profit.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good plan. I'll start with this.